# CRM 2011 Custom SQL based Report error "table alias is not unique amongst all top level table and join aliases

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I receive this error quite often whenever I try to modify the Standard filter for my SQL based report. The reason for this error is that table alias in joins is set to a some non unique value on modifying the filter.

I spent a lot of time to find any solution for it but failed. Then found a workaround for it my self.

Open data base OrganizationName_MSCRM and execute following query

select DefaultFilter from dbo.ReportBase where Name = 'My SQL based report name'

Copy the value of the default filter and open in an XML file. You will find alias="a_3513cef8db754312b0db555339f05c9a" in the XML. Change the GUID in the alias with some other GUID and update back the ReportBase table DefaultFilter value.

Run the report and it will work.

Comment: Readers should be aware that direct database changes are not supported, you'll lose Microsoft support on your installation and any error while touching the database might make your CRM non-functional.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid running updates directly against your CRM database (which, as [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999042/alex) said, is unsupported), you may be able to modify the default filter in the RDL itself.

First, you have to download the RDL and open it as an XML or text file.  You can do this in any text editor (and in VS.NET if the RDL isn't in an BIDS Report Server Project).

Near the bottom, you will find a section similar to the following:

```
    <CustomProperties><CustomProperty><Name>Custom</Name><Value>&lt;MSCRM
     xmlns="mscrm"&gt;&amp;lt;ReportFilter&amp;gt;&amp;lt;ReportEntity 
     paramname="P1"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" 
     mapping="logical" distinct="false"&amp;gt;
```

The Value is the default filter for the RDL.  The Value is XML encoded twice, but if you run it through a decoder, like the one at http://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=xml, you'll get something more readable:

1st Decode

```
     <MSCRM xmlns="mscrm">&lt;ReportFilter&gt;&lt;ReportEntity 
     paramname="P1"&gt;&lt;fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" 
     mapping="logical" distinct="false"&gt;
```

2nd Decode

```
    <ReportFilter><ReportEntity 
     paramname="P1"><fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" 
     mapping="logical" distinct="false">
```

Include everything through the closing `</Value>`, and you'll get the FetchXML that defines the default filter.

Change the guid, or remove the `<LinkEntity>` section that includes the alias.  As long as you have valid FetchXML, you should be able to upload the file as a new report.

Re-Encode (x2) the XML and put it back in the RDL.  First encode the fetch XML, then wrap it in the `<MSCRM xmlns="mscrm"></MSCRM>` element, and encode that string.  Be sure that your encoder does not replace the `"` with `&quot;`.  The one at coderstoolbox.net will, but CRM doesn't do this when encoding the XML.

You must upload your RDL as a new report.  In my testing, CRM will not update the defaultfilter column in the database with the filter in the RDL when updating an existing report.

I know this is a lot of hoop-jumping, and I can't say whether this type of customization is officially supported.  Personally, I feel safer uploading an RDL through the CRM web UI than I do with an open SSMS terminal running update statements against the database.

Answer (score 1):

I followed a similar solution as Scott Stone - but only exported the report, searched for the 'offending' join, modified the GUID and, as Scott also mentioned, deleted and then re-uploaded the report. (as opposed to simply re-uploading the modified RDL into the existing report.)